# Data model for multi variable time based data

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-modeling

I have multiple sheets of data in the following format.

- The columns are days (time series) which keeps increasing as time progress
- The variables are in rows which remains the same across categories
- Category 1 takes 3 values and Category 2 takes 2 values so there are 6 combinations of sheets every day.

[image: Existing data in excel sheets]

I need to capture this data into a database. I am seeking help and suggestions as to how i need to setup the schema. Below are some of the considerations.

- I intend to do a lot of calculations on the variables, for instance trend of variable 1 x variable 10 for Category1 & Category 2 month over month.
- The database will be updated daily from six sheets x 30 variables x 1 column (day) data which is 180 data points every day.
- We would need to summarize the data across categories - Category 1(Val 1, Val 2, Val 3) in (Val 2 in Category 2)
- Flexibility to add more values in Category 1 and 2 in the future.

My initial design is as follows. I don't know whether it makes sense to separate the data into different relational tables. I was thinking along the lines of a transactional database and have views for specific categories. So every day 180 rows would get added to the database.

[image]

Comment: So which DBMS is it? Microsoft SQL Server or PostgreSQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a sound desing you came-up with. Translated to SQL:

```
create table timesheet (
    day date not null,
    cat1 int not null,
    cat2 int not null,
    var1 double precision not null,
    var2 double precision not null,
    var3 double precision not null,
    -- ... --
    var30 double precision not null,
    primary key (day, cat1, cat2)
);
```

---

> trend of variable 1 x variable 10 for Category1 & Category 2 month over month.

Not very precise, but maybe something like:

```
select 
    extract(year from current_date)*100+extract(month from current_date) as month,
    avg(var1*var10) as avg_mul_var1_var10
from timesheet
where cat1=? and cat2=?
group by month
order by month;
```

---

> views for specific categories

Don't do that - you just query the database with parameters like in above query.

---

> So every day 180 rows would get added to the database.

No - only 6 rows. One for each cat1 and cat2 combination. That's 180 values per day and only 2190 rows per year.

Comment: Thanks for the SQL code. I am new to db schema design. I was looking at some db designs where the data is represented as relational model - foreign keys etc. Is it worth exploring those relational schemas?